# How to grant usage on generator syntax

Tags: permissions, firebird, sql-grant, sequence-sql, firebird-4.0

I'm usually not the one working with Firebird language, but I have to fix access to generators in order to continue working. There is one line in my script: `set generator order_gen to 0` that doesn't work anymore.

I'm trying: `GRANT USAGE ON GENERATOR ORDER_GEN TO USER MAHE`, but I still get the error `...no permission for ALTER access to GENERATOR ORDER_GEN ...`.

Should I be granting a different privilege to be able to set the generator, or am I not using the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Firebird 3.0 or higher, the `USAGE` privilege only grants the privilege for using `NEXT VALUE FOR <sequence>` and `GEN_ID(<sequence>, <n>)`. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-security-granting.html#fblangref40-security-grant-usage):

> For sequences (generators), the `USAGE` privilege only grants the
> right to increment the sequence using the `GEN_ID` function or `NEXT VALUE FOR`. **The `SET GENERATOR` statement is a synonym for `ALTER SEQUENCE …​ RESTART WITH …​`, and is considered a DDL statement.** By
> default, only the owner of the sequence and administrators have the
> rights to such operations. The right to set the initial value of any
> sequence can be granted with `GRANT ALTER ANY SEQUENCE`, which is not
> recommend for general users.

As mentioned, `GRANT ALTER ANY SEQUENCE` should be a last resort. Depending on the actual problem being solved, you could also do something like calling `gen_id(order_gen, 0 - gen_id(order_gen, 0))` (e.g. as `select gen_id(order_gen, 0 - gen_id(order_gen, 0)) from rdb$database`) (this is a loophole/workaround, see also [Inconsistency between ALTER and USAGE privileges for sequences (generators).](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/6193) in the Firebird issue tracker).

Alternatively, you should ask your database administrator to execute this script/statement, or - if you have the RDB$ADMIN privilege yourself - to ensure you specify that role when connecting to the database (if you don't explicitly specify the role, you don't get the administrator privileges).

Comment: We just switched over to Firebird 4.0, and also removed all admin privileges from the main user that we're writing scripts for, only granting stuff when needed. I do have admin privilege. I just missed that part in the documentation as I'm not really used to working with Firebird. Thank you!